# questions in r about mu and polygon

Tags: r

I am a beginner in r language, and I am trying hard to improve.
I have found some questions while learning t,z-test and polygon in r language.
I hope to get some help from amazing experts in r in this site.
first I can't figure out how to designate specific area in polygon.
If I want to designate specific area in normal distribution, how can I do that?
Second, I don't understand what 'mu' means in t-test and z-test.
I think it means specific standard, but I don't know when to use 'mu'.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO! It would be great if you could post some code so that others can help you.

Comment: Oh sorry..!!! I must do so next time! Thanks for letting me know how to get more help!!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems a rather unfocused question, but I think you are asking how to use `polygon` to highlight a segment of a normal distribution.

The following function will draw a normal distribution for you:

```r
plot_dnorm <- function(xmin, xmax, n = 1000, mu = 0, sd = 1, 
                       xlab = "Value", ylab = "Density", ...)
{
  x <- seq(xmin, xmax, length.out = n)
  plot(x, dnorm(x, mu, sd), type = "l", xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, ...)
}
```

You use it by supplying the lower and upper ends of the range you wish to plot. If you want, you can supply a mean and standard deviation as well. If not, it will default to mean 0 and standard deviation 1.

```
plot_dnorm(-3, 3)
```

[image]

To overlay a polygon, you need to work out what the x and y co-ordinates are that you want it to have. You can get a polygon that traces a segment of a normal distribution using this function:

```r
plot_partial_dnorm <- function(xmin, xmax, n = 1000, mu = 0, 
                               sd = 1, fill = "lightgray")
{
  x <- seq(xmin, xmax, length.out = n)
  y <- c(0, dnorm(x, mu, sd), 0)
  x <- c(xmin, x, xmax)
  polygon(x, y, col = fill)
}
```

Again, you just tell it the range you want to plot and the mean and standard deviation you want. You can also change the color of its fill.

So you can create a plot like this:

```
plot_dnorm(xmin = 0, xmax = 10, mu = 6.5, sd = 2)
plot_partial_dnorm(xmin = 4, xmax = 6, mu = 6.5, sd = 2, fill = "forestgreen")
```

[image]

As for your question about what `mu` means in `t.test`, this is more of a statistics question than a programming question, but essentially it is the value against which you are testing the mean of your sample. You would use it most often when doing a single-sample t.test.

For example, suppose you took a sample of men's heights in your home town to find out whether they were taller or shorter than the known national average of 175.3 cm. You would pass your vector of measurements into the t.test and set `mu = 175.3`. The result of the t.test would tell you the probability that the mean height of men in your town is drawn from a population with the same mean as the national average. In other words, if you get a low p value, the average height of men in your town is likely to be different from the national average.

If you are doing a t.test to compare the mean of two samples (e.g. you have a sample of men's heights and women's heights) and you want to know if men are significantly taller than women, then you leave mu at zero. Then you are asking "what is the probability that the difference between men's average height and women's average height is zero?"

Comment: I am really sorry for my unfocused questions..!! However you kindly gave examples and instructions! Thank you so much for your kindness. I wish I know some ways to express my gratefulness in this site..but I don't know how to..so I'll just express it in words. Anyway thanks to you, now I understand why mu value is set in specific numbers, especially '0'! And I got the idea that I should supply upper and lower ends in polygon, and I succeeded in my r problem. Thank you so much again!!!:)